# Javascript outputing result with one second in between

Tags: javascript

New Javascript student here. Currently, this is the code that I have

```js
 function trial(number) {
    let arr = [11, 4, 5]
    console.log("Number:", number)
    setTimeout(() => {
        for (let nums in arr) {
            console.log("Num", arr[nums])
            if (arr[nums] == number) {
                console.log("A")
            } else {
                console.log("B")
            }
        }
    }, 1000)
}
trial(5)
```

when I input `trial([11])` it will wait for 1 second and gives all 3 results. How do I make it so that it will wait 1 second - print `Num 11 A`, wait another second - `Num 4 B` and finally another second for `Num 5 B`? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to set your Timeout inside of the for loop

Comment: @PixAff that will not work unless the for loop is async and he uses await/promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`.

```js
function trial(number) {
  let arr = [11, 4, 5]
  console.log("Number:", number)
  let i = 0;
  let id = setInterval(() => {
    if(i === arr.length) return clearInterval(id);
    const num = arr[i++];
    console.log("Num", num)
    if (num == number) {
      console.log("A")
    } else {
      console.log("B")
    }
  }, 1000)
}
trial(11);
```